# How to share an Id between multiple views in Laravel

Tags: laravel

In my project, there is a list of projects for each user, when a user clicks on one of his projects he will go to a sub-system(Project Manager) dashboard, and this sub-system has multiple views

I am returning this sub-system dashboard with the id of the project from a controller.

How can I share the Id of the project between all the views of the sub-system, not the dashboard only?

Comment: If you are yielding the "sub view" then you should have access to the data. Otherwise refer here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Comment: How do you assign sub-system to project in first place, i.e. how do you create/save sub-system? Does sub-system have `project_id` in table (exclusively projects should be projectable maybe [study polymorphic relation for that])? If so you have project data available. If not, it should.

Answer (score 0):

In Controller or Service provider , you can add

```
View::share('your_shared_variable_name', 'SomeValue');
```

in any **Blade** template in your project you can use,

```
{{ $your_shared_variable_name }}
```

**Note**: Be careful when using this with wildcards like View::share('folder.*') especially when your variable is retrieving from a database query. Every blade file being included or rendered makes 1 extra query and ends up making tons of the same query per blade file. For analyse you can use laravel-debugbar or telescope package.

Comment: What is the propper way of using it in the controller, my function is ( return view('projectManagement/dashboard',['data'=>$data]);)

Comment: yes it is. and also you can use view share without wildcard.